# Summarize rows based on multiple cells

Tags: pivot-table, libreoffice-calc

Let's say columns 1-10 are identifiers and 11-15 are values. Identifiers might occur multiple times and I'd like to add up the values in each column. Example:

```
A1|B1|1|2|
A1|B1|5|3|
A2|B2|3|6|
A2|B2|4|2|
```

should become:

```
A1|B1|6|5|
A2|B2|7|8|
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a straightforward case for a Pivot Table.

1. Add column headings in the first row: `Identifier 1|Identifier 2|Value 1|Value 2`.
2. Select the data (A1 to D5 in this example) and go to Data -> Pivot Table -> Create.
3. Drag `Identifier 1` and `Identifier 2` to Row Fields, and `Value 1` and `Value 2` to Data Fields.  Uncheck `Total Rows` and `Total Columns`.

[image: Pivot Table Layout]

The result:

[image: Pivot Table result]